# How to rename bucket and folder in GCS using the UI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to change the name of my bucket **and** the name of the folder in the bucket using the web UI of GCS.

The options of the bucket (three dots):

[image]

The options of the folder (three dots):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

John Michael G is right, it's not possible to rename bucket. Directories, on their side, doesn't exist, and the answer is obvious!!

About the move proposed in the answer, take care of it. Even if, on the UI and in the client library (in Python for example), the MOVE operation seems existing, it doesn't exist in reality. The MOVE operation perform a copy from the OLD pathname to the NEW pathname, and then delete the OLD pathname

*NOTE: it's important to know especially when you perform these operation because extra cost can be occured.*

Extra: Renaming a file doesn't also exist. the same operation as a move (COPY and DELETE) is performed.

---

For the bucket, the right solution is to perform a copy. BUT, if you have a large number of file, the copy will take hours, or even days (for each file, you perform an API call and that take some millis or few seconds and with thousands of file, it's very very very long.)

In this case, I recommend to setup a [file transfert](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview) with Cloud Storage and let the run going in background. Error management and retries are performed for you automatically.

Comment: I wonder why this is not possible? Probably something to do with gcs being optimised for static files... Still some sort of 'magic button' that does copy and delete automatically would be nice

Comment: I think it's the design of the solution. Each optimisation has tradeoff.

Answer (score 5):

Cloud Storage Bucket name and folder can't be renamed. There is an alternative way you can do it:

For folder:

- Use the gsutil command by moving the old directory to new directory:

> `gsutil mv gs://<bucketname>/olddir gs://<bucketname>/newdir`

For bucket:

- Create a new bucket name then move or copy your data from the old bucket to the new bucket and delete the old bucket.

Comment: is this command downloading the files then uploading with new prefix, when source and target both are gs://xxx?